# Wordpress REST API: Filter custom post type with multiple filters

Tags: php, json, wordpress, wp-api, wordpress-rest-api

I've a custom post type "products" for which I created custom field with the *Advanced Custom Fields* (ACF) plugin.

When I request *products* with `/wp-json/wp/v2/products` every product has acf attributes e.g.:

```
"acf": {
  "rating": 77
  "fun-factor": 10,
  "something": 65,
  …
}
```

Now I filter my `products` by my attribute by `/wp-json/wp/v2/products?filter[meta_key]=rating&filter[meta_value]=77` and would get my *product* above back as an result. So far so good.

Now I've two things I want to accomplish:

- Show *products* with a *rating* range between 67-87, so *value - 10* and *value + 10*
- Do the request with multiple filters

Im happy for any input!

Comment: did you found a solution?

Comment: did you found a solution

Comment: https://github.com/airesvsg/acf-to-wp-rest-api/issues/6